# Recover PostgreSQL database data

Tags: postgresql, recovery

I am using PostgreSQL in my project, Now by mistake I have deleted some records of one of my tables. Now is there any way to recover deleted Records in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this can help [How to recover deleted records](https://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2005-01/msg00176.php) where Michael Fuhr says:

> If you haven't VACUUMed the database then the deleted rows are
> probably still there.  I don't know if any recovery tools exist,
> but to have any chance of recovering the data make a filesystem
> backup of $PGDATA as soon as possible, or at least make a backup
> of the table's file(s) (see below).  They might not do you any good,
> but you'll probably need those files if you do find any recovery
> tools.
>
> If you don't find any recovery tools and you *really* need to get
> the data back, then you might enjoy reading the chapter describing
> page file formats in the documentation ("Page Files" in PostgreSQL
> 7.x; "Database Physical Storage" in the upcoming 8.0).
>
> You can find out which files hold a table's data by querying
> pg_database and pg_class.

Answer (score -2):

In front of DML statements you need write "begin;" .In execution time you need to execute with DML statement along with begin .Then execute rollback statement

EXAMPLE:-
step1:-
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (CONDITION);
setp2:-
ROLLBACK;